# Export and combine SQL Table with relations

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, export

I need to export all Products as CSV from an online-shop to import them into a other system.

The products are split into multiple tables with relations to each other.

I tried exporting it via phpMyAdmin interface but it exports not the full relational data. I found about SQL `JOIN` and `UNION` but no idea how to execute them.

One Idea I had was to create a new temp_table and import all my necessary tables into it but I don't know how.

### Table Example

**table: products**

```
| product_id | product_weight | 
|------------|----------------|
|      1     |       1.4      |
|      2     |       2.3      |
```

**table: product_details**

```
| product_id | product_name | 
|------------|--------------|
|      1     |     Wine     |
|      2     |     Beer     |
```

**table: product_prices**

```
| product_id | product_price | 
|------------|---------------|
|      1     |     18.22     |
|      2     |     3.20      |
```

### Export should be a combination of those

```
| product_id | product_weight | product_name | product_price | 
|------------|----------------|--------------|---------------|
|      1     |      18.22     |     Wine     |     18.22     |
|      2     |      3.20      |     Beer     |     3.20      |
```

Comment: Without product_id ???

Comment: @GerardH.Pille probably with the id, I don't know. The new system should generate a new ID.

Comment: Each product can only have one name and one price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `INNER JOIN`. Try like:

```
SELECT product_weight
    ,product_name
    ,product_price
FROM products pr
INNER JOIN product_prices prp ON pr.product_id - prp.product_id
INNER JOIN product_details prd ON pr.product_id = prd.product_id
```

If you want to create a new table, try:

```
SELECT product_weight
        ,product_name
        ,product_price
INTO myNewTable
 FROM products pr
    INNER JOIN product_prices prp ON pr.product_id - prp.product_id
    INNER JOIN product_details prd ON pr.product_id = prd.product_id
```

Comment: How would you generate a new table for that? I don't want to override exisitng tables.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  p.product_weight,
  pd.product_name,
  pp.product_price
FROM
  products AS p
INNER JOIN
  product_details AS pd
ON
  pd.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN
  product_prices AS pp
ON
  pp.product_id = p.product_id
```